# Has any one seen this sum of roots of unity before?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-analysis, roots-of-unity

Fix a prime $p >2$ and $q_1$, $q_2$ such that $q_i - 1$ is exactly divisible by $p$. For any $n$, $a$, $b $, consider the sum

$$\sum_{i=0}^{p^{n-1}-1}\zeta_{p^n}^{aq_1^i+bq_2^i}.$$

Is this always divisible by $p^{n-1}$? In fact, perhaps it is always $0$ or all the summands are equal? I believe the following question is also relevant. For any j, is

$$\sum_{i=0}^{p^{n-1}-1}\zeta_{p^n}^{pij+bq_2^i} \equiv 0 \pmod{p^{n-1}}? $$

(If $q_1 =q_2$, I think this is true and not hard to see. I am really interested in a more general version but this is the easiest case I don't know how to do.)

Comment: Does "exactly divisible by $p$" mean "divisible by $p$ but not by $p^2$" here?

Comment: Yes. This is not an important constraint, I only chose it to make thing explicit. In general the sum should be large enough so that you cover an entire period for $(q_1^i,q_2^i)$.

Comment: Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the sagemath code,

```
p = 5
q1 = p+1
q2 = 2*p+1
n = 3
a = 3
b = 1
k = CyclotomicField(p^n)
s = sum([k.gen()^(a*q1^i+b*q2^i) for i in range(0,p^(n-1))])
(s/p^(n-1)).norm()
```

it output 1/88817841970012523233890533447265625. Hence, the answer is no.

Comment: For this example Mathematica gives: $zeta = Exp[2 Pi I/125];
\sum _{i=0}^{24} \text{zeta}^{3\ 6^i+11^i}$
gives
$$5 e^{\frac{8 i \pi }{125}}+
10 e^{-\frac{1}{125} (42 i \pi )}+10 e^{\frac{58 i \pi }{125}}$$, which gives
N[\%]
10.9551 +2.23283 i.
With $a=1$ it is numerically close to $0$.

Can anybody else check this independently?